# ng-animate not working with animate.css

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, animate.css

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.yearofmoo.com/animation-presentation/#/7) trying to implement animation in my app. But for some reason I cant do it. [Here is the planker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eQSdHo0gDXWUvNyTU2Tt?p=preview) I have made.

Here is how I am adding the ng-animate attribute:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" class="{enter:'animated bounceIn',leave:'animated bounceOut'}">{{item}}</li>
```

**Note:** I am using [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animations aren't working because Angular applies some classes to the elements for the animations such as:  `ng-enter`, `ng-leave`, etc.  So, we just need to wire these up with the animations:

Here is an example:

```
<style>
 li.ng-enter {
-webkit-animation: bounceIn 0.5s;
animation: bounceIn 0.5s;
 }
 li.ng-leave {
   -webkit-animation: bounceOut 0.5s;
animation: bounceOut 0.5s;

 }
 </style>
```

In your html somewhere:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items"  >{{item}}</li>
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/c8uvhQXtXgdfsEHRo9P6?p=preview

The angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate) lists the classes it uses.

Comment: how should I apply this on elements with class (`<li class="test">bla</li>`)

Comment: And I cant make it work for ng-show, here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/eQSdHo0gDXWUvNyTU2Tt?p=preview

Comment: You should follow standard css rulings:  `li.test.ng-enter {}` etc.  Your second comment doesn't have an ng-show.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow  take a look at the angular docs.

Comment: So need to create tow elements with different classes?

Comment: ngShow/Hide uses a different class.  It is in the docs.. Here is the plunker referenced in the angular docs.  http://plnkr.co/edit/tYIDsgATPadQ9J2lvDay?p=preview