# ng-show animation works not as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, animation

I have created [this pulnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eQSdHo0gDXWUvNyTU2Tt?p=preview). Both enter an leave animation are not working well...
The enter- first appears and then animation kicks in.
The leave- just wont animate.

Here is the style:

```
   div.ng-enter 
   {
    -webkit-animation: bounceIn 2s;
    animation: bounceIn 2s;
   }
   div.ng-leave 
   {
     -webkit-animation: bounceOut 2s;
    animation: bounceOut 2s;
   }
```

And here is the element node:

```
<div ng-show="show" ng-class="{true:'ng-enter', false: 'ng-leave'}[show]">asdasdas</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The code in your plunker looks nothing like what you have here...

Comment: Find a proper tutorial on ng-animate.

Comment: Which one do you want to solve? plunker or this? I've seen your previous question and fixed, but it is closed before I answer.

Comment: I want this one (as in the question). The plunker should look like what I have posted. I have just tested the link.

Comment: I answered this in your last question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686950/ng-animate-not-working-with-animate-css/24687283#24687283  See the comments.

Comment: Sorry try http://plnkr.co/edit/1hEXqwF7e04IwH0gtuBm?p=preview again I didn't add the css to match.

Comment: @Dylan, your example is for ng-repeat, I am talking about ng-show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few changes in 1.2.0 rc1 [re-plunkered](http://plnkr.co/edit/1hEXqwF7e04IwH0gtuBm?p=preview)

```
class="repeat-item"
```

and the enter/leave are assumed css

```
.repeat-item.ng-enter, 
.repeat-item.ng-leave {...}
```

here's more details from [yearofmoo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)

Here is the plunker for ng-show: http://plnkr.co/edit/0hHjG4RQ3tQngwd814Tg?p=preview

Comment: This is not the the issue, you show how to do this with repeat. I am talking about show/hide. take a look at the plunker in the question.

Comment: That's weird, ng-hide-add is hide - http://plnkr.co/edit/0hHjG4RQ3tQngwd814Tg?p=preview